# CefSharp Winforms - Some Web-Sites load then goes blank

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, cefsharp

CefSharp work well, except for a couple of specific web-sites will load and then go blank; which takes about 5 seconds after it loads.  I can reload them.. and, they will go blank again; after about another 5 seconds.
The problem sites will have a Pop-Up window that asks to Allow Access.  Regardless if I click yes/no, they'll go blank.

One specific web-site is HomeDepot.com.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Here's the debug.log file generated by CefSharp:
`[0525/092340.245:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(107)] CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) [0525/092340.346:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(211)] Crash reporting enabled for process: renderer [0525/092340.384:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0) [0525/092340.455:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(107)] CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) [0525/092340.582:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(211)] Crash reporting enabled for process: renderer [0525/092342.383:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 64424509447 [15,7] .... [0525/092342.387:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 64424509450 [15,10] ... [0525/092342.393:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 64424509453 [15,13] .... [0525/092342.414:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 64424509456 [15,16] .... [0525/092342.540:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 64424509459 [15,19] [0525/092342.542:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(107)] CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) .... [0525/092342.546:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 64424509462 [15,22] .... [0525/092342.715:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(211)] Crash reporting enabled for process: renderer [0525/092343.792:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 68719476749 [16,13] [0525/092343.882:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(107)] CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) [0525/092344.003:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(211)] Crash reporting enabled for process: renderer [0525/092344.113:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 68719476749 [16,13] .... [0525/092344.115:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0) [0525/092347.593:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(107)] CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) [0525/092347.710:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(211)] Crash reporting enabled for process: renderer [0525/092348.551:WARNING:frame_impl.cc(431)] SendProcessMessage sent to detached frame 60129542148 [14,4] will be ignored`

Here's the Unmodified Minimal Example (Winforms):
`[0527/094208.587:ERROR:crashpad_client_win.cc(527)] CreateProcess: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) [0527/094208.635:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(211)] Crash reporting enabled for process: browser [0527/094228.839:WARNING:frame_impl.cc(431)] SendProcessMessage sent to detached frame 21474836481 [5,1] will be ignored [0527/094231.433:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 30064771078 [7,6] [0527/094231.745:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 30064771078 [7,6] [0527/094231.745:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 30064771078 [7,6] [0527/094231.745:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 30064771078 [7,6] [0527/094231.746:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 30064771078 [7,6] [0527/094231.898:WARNING:media_session.cc(941)] RED codec red is missing an associated payload type. [0527/094231.975:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:42:31.975] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1075 Getting Default Adapter failed. [0527/094232.117:WARNING:stun_port.cc(434)] Port[1553200:0:1:0:local:Net[any:0:0:0:x:x:x:x:x/0:Wildcard:id=0]]: StunPort: stun host lookup received error 0 [0527/094234.530:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 34359738376 [8,8] [0527/094234.551:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 34359738376 [8,8] [0527/094234.551:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 34359738376 [8,8] [0527/094234.551:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 34359738376 [8,8] [0527/094234.552:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 34359738376 [8,8] [0527/094351.382:ERROR:shared_buffer_dispatcher.cc(192)] Invalid serialized shared buffer dispatcher (invalid num_bytes?) [0527/094353.756:WARNING:media_session.cc(941)] RED codec red is missing an associated payload type. [0527/094353.775:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:43:53.775] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1075 Getting Default Adapter failed. [0527/094354.170:WARNING:stun_port.cc(434)] Port[38dce00:0:1:0:local:Net[any:0:0:0:x:x:x:x:x/0:Wildcard:id=0]]: StunPort: stun host lookup received error 0 [0527/094356.818:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 47244640263 [11,7] [0527/094356.818:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 47244640263 [11,7] [0527/094356.818:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 47244640263 [11,7] [0527/094356.819:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 47244640263 [11,7] [0527/094356.819:WARNING:browser_info.cc(298)] Returning a speculative frame for 47244640263 [11,7] [0527/094408.888:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(481)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is  [0527/094421.851:WARNING:webrtc_voice_engine.cc(659)] Attempting to stop aecdump when no audio processing module is present [0527/094422.644:WARNING:frame_impl.cc(431)] SendProcessMessage sent to detached frame 25769803799 [6,23] will be ignored [0527/094422.644:WARNING:frame_impl.cc(431)] OnDidFinishLoad sent to detached frame 25769803799 [6,23] will be ignored [0527/094422.644:WARNING:frame_impl.cc(431)] SendProcessMessage sent to detached frame 25769803799 [6,23] will be ignored [0527/094422.661:WARNING:frame_impl.cc(431)] SendProcessMessage sent to detached frame 25769803800 [6,24] will be ignored [0527/094422.661:WARNING:frame_impl.cc(431)] OnDidFinishLoad sent to detached frame 25769803800 [6,24] will be ignored [0527/094422.661:WARNING:frame_impl.cc(431)] SendProcessMessage sent to detached frame 25769803800 [6,24] will be ignored`

Comment: What version are you using? Are there any errors in the log file or the devtools console? Sounds like the render process has crashed. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Comment: Testing with the WinForms example provided as part of https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample (targeting x64) and https://www.homedepot.com/ loads as expected, I can navigate around the site without problem. If you are using a version older than 101.0.180 then I'd suggest upgrading.

Comment: Current Version: 99.2.140.

Comment: .. Updated to 101.0.180, but that still goes blank after about 7 seconds...

Comment: I added the debug.log file to my original question.

Comment: Please test with the minimal example

Comment: Is the error log above from your application or the minimal example? Looks like a lot of those errors are coming from crashpad.

Comment: The error above is mostly from the minimal example... It's the minimal example, but I've added code around it.  The Error log is from Debug.log found in the `bin\AnyCPU\Debug\net452\debug.log`

Comment: Please test with an unmodified copy of the minimal example, targeting x64 or x86. Crashpad won't work properly targeting AnyCPU.

Comment: Yes, the Minimal Example (Winforms) does not go blank.  I've posted the debug.log info in my original post..

Comment: What do you mean by The error above is mostly from the minimal example? Are you using a modified version? Or just you copied some code?

Comment: Using the 'Minimal Example' CefSharp **does not** go blank.  (I've pasted the debug.log info into my original post.)  2.) what I meant earlier, was my program started as 'minimal example', and it now has been altered extensively.

Comment: Make sure your application has an app.manifest that includes windows compatibility entries. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/app.manifest#L55 (if you forked the minimal example it should already be there). If that checks out then I need an example that reproduces the problem. Ideally fork the minimum example and push your changes to GitHub, just the code required to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for basic guidance.